# Using a pointer by reference variable in linked lists

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

How do I refer to the tail variable inside the take_input() function so that it reflects in the main ?
Below are the main() and take_input() functions
Here I've tried to pass by reference [ **tail ]
How do I refer to this inside the take_input() function for the linked list { *tail is causing an error }

Any help would be highly appreciated !!!!

```
node* take_input(node **tail)
    {
        
        node* head = NULL;
        int count = 0;
        string name;
 
        cout << "Enter the name of the president";
        cin >> name;

        while(!name.empty())
        { 
            
            count++ ;
            node *new_node = new node(name);
            if(head == NULL)
            {
                head = new_node;
                *tail = new_node;
            }
            else
            {
                *tail->next = new_node ;
                *tail= *tail->next;
            }

            cout << "Enter the name of a member , the secretary or NULL to exit";
            cin >> name ;
            
            
            
         }
               return head;

     }
        int main()
        {
            int n ;
            string name;
            node *tail = NULL;
       
        
           node *head =  take_input(&tail);
       
           cin >> n;
           cin >> name;

           node *headfinal = insert_node(head, n ,name);

           cout<< "\n Enter the member's name which needs to be deleted\n";
           string del;
           cin >> del;

           node *head_final2 = delete_node(headfinal,del, &tail);

           node *temp2 = head_final2 ;
       
           while(temp2 != NULL)
           {
               cout << temp2->name;
               temp2 = temp2->next;
           
           }
```

This is the error I am currently facing:

expression must have a pointer to class type (c/c++) (131,5)

Comment: EASY on the ALL CAPS. It's YELLING. Also avoid adding emphasis in your code, as `**` has meaning in C++ that isn't "bold". If you need to, add comments with `//` or `/* ... */`.

Comment: You can pass a reference to a pointer, i.e. `node * take_input (node * & tail)`. Then in main, you can simply call `node * head = take_input(tail);`.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's `NULL`. Also there's a strong convention to not have any space around `->`, so use `x->y` to make it clear what's going on there.

Comment: @tadman Okay I'll be more careful next time

Comment: @Dhardhuk How do i refer to it inside the take_input function where I'm entering the linked list?

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you can find that `->` has a higher precedence than `*`. You have to use parenthesis: `*tail->next = new_node;` -> `(*tail)->next = new_node;` and `*tail = *tail->next;` -> `*tail = (*tail)->next;`

Comment: thanks @ThomasSablik that solves my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by Thomas Sabnik in the comments:

`->` has higher precedence than `*`. You have to use parenthesis:

Change `*tail->next = new_node;` to `(*tail)->next = new_node;` and
`*tail = *tail->next;` to `*tail = (*tail)->next;`.